# C# & ASP.NET Web API: return Ok(returnData); statement is slow

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

For an ASP.NET Web API using Linq, I am doing a bunch of operations that complete relatively quickly when I step through them using the debugger once the endpoint is called through Swagger.

However, once I arrive at the return statement, it takes *ages* to complete - several seconds up to minutes.

I have no idea why this would be happening - I imagine it is some kind of slow serialization from the classes to the JSON fields in the HTTP response?

Here is the relevant code:

View models:

```
public class RetriesAtGoal
{
    public string goal { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string retries { get; set; }
    public int total_retries { get; set; }
}

public class SuccessfulApproaches
{
    public string goal { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class ApproachesReturnDataViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<RetriesAtGoal> retriesAtGoal { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SuccessfulApproaches> successfulApproaches { get; set; }
}
```

Code in API:

```
var returnData = new ApproachesReturnDataViewModel { };

var totalRetries = db.message
                     .Select(x => new 
                                  { 
                                      type = x.type, 
                                      agvId = x.agvId, 
                                      createdTimestamp = x.createdTimestamp, 
                                      source = x.source, 
                                      details = x.details 
                                  })
                     .Where(x => x.type == "ErrorHandling" && 
                                 robotList.Contains(x.agvId) && 
                                 x.createdTimestamp >= start && 
                                 x.createdTimestamp < end)
                     .ToList();

// <1 second
returnData.retriesAtGoal = totalRetries
                                .GroupBy(x => new { x.source, x.details })
                                .Select((x, y) => new RetriesAtGoal
                                                      {
                                                          goal = x.FirstOrDefault().source,
                                                          count = x.Count(),
                                                          retries = x.FirstOrDefault().details,
                                                          total_retries = x.Count() * (int.Parse(x.FirstOrDefault().details) == 0 ? 1 : int.Parse(x.FirstOrDefault().details + 1))
                                                      });

// 4 seconds
var totalSuccessful = db.job
                        .Include(x => x.jobGoals)
                        .Select(x => new 
                                     { 
                                         createdTimestamp = x.createdTimestamp, 
                                         assignedAgvId = x.assignedAgvId, 
                                         jobGoals = x.jobGoals, 
                                         id = x.id 
                                     })
                        .Where(x => x.createdTimestamp >= start && 
                                    x.createdTimestamp < end && 
                                    robotList.Contains(x.assignedAgvId) && 
                                    x.jobGoals.Count() == 2)
                        .ToList();

// <1 second
returnData.successfulApproaches = totalSuccessful
    .SelectMany(x => new[] { new { goal = x.jobGoals.First().goalId, job_id = x.id },
                    new { goal = x.jobGoals.Last().goalId, job_id = x.id } })
     .Where(x => !messageCompare.Any(e => e.affectedJobId == x.job_id && e.source == x.goal))
     .GroupBy(x => x.goal)
     .Select(x => new SuccessfulApproaches { goal = x.Key, count = x.Count() });

// Apparently takes very, very long!
return Ok(returnData);
```

Comment: It's not that `Ok(...)` is slow, it's that you passed it a lazily evaluated query, which in order for `Ok(...)` to figure out what to return, it has to fully evaluate. So all the code above is what is "slow", not necessarily `Ok(...)` itself.

Comment: Basically, when `returnData` is evaluated inside `Ok`, you will have to execute all the queries stacked together from the above code, which includes the database access. None of that has happened yet.

Comment: If you want to measure how long each query takes, materialize the assignments to `retriesAtGoal` and `successfulApproaches` by appending `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to the query.

Comment: Interesting, that explains it. Sad that the queries are so slow, I thought I optimized them a bit already.

Comment: at a glance the query retriesAtGoal  uses FirstOrDefault after group by and that will make sql larger than it could have been if you where to use the Key property as it already contains both source and details

Comment: The above mentioned evaluation in the last line is not true. Since @mneumann is using .ToList() on all db queries the queries have in fact happend before the last line (why would some of them 4 seconds if it were to be just an IQueryable)

How large is the returnData in your example? What Version of EF are we talking about?